# how to replace values of string variable placed in double quotes in perl

Tags: string, perl

I need to insert values of string variables placed in double quotes. I am using below code :-

```
$username="abc";
$password="123";
my $post_data = '{ "auth": {"tenantName":"admin", "passwordCredentials": {"username":"$username","password":"$password"} }}';
print $post_data;
```

It is showing output like :-

```
{ "auth": {"tenantName":"admin", "passwordCredentials": {"username":"$username","password":"$password"} }}
```

But i want output like :-

```
{ "auth": {"tenantName":"admin", "passwordCredentials": {"username":"abc","password":"123}"}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `qq` [**quoting operator**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) to explicitly set the interpolating behavior for an enclosed string literal, like this:

```
my $post_data = qq'{ "auth": {"tenantName":"admin", "passwordCredentials": {"username":"$username","password":"$password"} }}';
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/180746). Note that using single-quote as a delimiter here is actually not a good choice, as any new developer might get confused with it (expecting that string won't be interpolated). But, as shown in the doc, you can swap it for any non-whitespace character (as long as it's not in the string OR you can easily escape it there). For example:

```
my $post_data = qq~{ "auth": {"tenantName":"admin", "passwordCredentials": {"username":"$username","password":"$password"} }}~;
```

Still, the clearest approach would be writing the whole structure as a HoH literal, then encoding it into JSON. It'll look similar to:

```
use JSON;
my $username = 'abc';
my $password = '123';
my $post_data = {
  auth => {
    tenantName => 'admin',
    passwordCredentials => {
      username => $username,
      password => $password
    }
  }
};
print to_json($post_data);
```

Now the goal of the code is crystal clear. )

Comment: Re "Now the goal of the code is crystal clear", and it will work even if the password contains `"`

Comment: `qq` doesn't set the interpolating behaviour - it sets the string delimiter

Comment: @Borodin For `qq`, it's 'A double-quoted, interpolated string.' For `q`, it's 'A single-quoted, literal string.' The *operator* chosen affects whether or not compiler attempts to interpolate, doesn't it?

Comment: @raina77ow: Only in the same way that a double-quote `"` "sets the interpolating behaviour"

Comment: @Borodin Exactly in the same way. )

Comment: @raina77ow: But a double quote doesn't support the point you are making! "Just use a double quote" wouldn't suffice.

Comment: @Borodin Actually it would have been (apart from the bug mentioned by ikegami), if the original string didn't contain `"` symbol. ) The point is, using `qq` operator on a string literal enclosed in single quotes _results_ in an interpolation.

Comment: @raina77ow: Fair enough. Then I apologise: I misunderstood the point you were making. By the way, @ikegami's comment was pointing out a further advantage of using `to_json`. He wasn't indicating a bug. +1 anyway

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way:

```
my $post_data = sprintf '{ "auth": {"tenantName":"admin", "passwordCredentials": {"username":"%s","password":"%s"} }}', $username, $password;
```

But i suggest you to use JSON module, and create json with it